# How to use Avro serialization with Spring-Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to learn Kafka and now Avro, To keep consistency between the sender object and receiver object, we keep a JSON schema (.avsc). but I am not able to find any simple example of how to use it. some example is using confluent (is confluent mandate for Avro), some are generating object via Avro tool.
so far I have a working Kafka setup.

> Object class

```
package com.example.kafka;
public class Hello {
String name;
String age;
public Hello(String name, String age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hello{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", date='" + age + '\'' +
            '}';
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

> Controler Class

```
    package com.example.kafka;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class KafkaController {
    @Autowired
    KafkaService kafkaService;
    @GetMapping("test")
    public Hello hello() {
        Hello hello = new Hello("shrikant", "25");
        kafkaService.hello(hello);
        return hello;
    }
}
```

> Main Application

```
package com.example.kafka;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class KafkaDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> KafkaProducerConfig

```
package com.example.kafka;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Hello> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Hello> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

> KafkaSerializer

```
package com.example.kafka;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import java.util.Map;
public class KafkaSerializer implements Serializer<Hello> {
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String arg0, Hello developer) {
        byte[] serializedBytes = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            serializedBytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(developer).getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return serializedBytes;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

> KafkaService

```
package com.example.kafka;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class KafkaService {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Hello> kafkaTemplate;
    public void hello(Hello hello) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("test", hello);
    }
}
```

> Hello.avsc

```
{"namespace": "com.example.kafka",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Hello",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "age",  "type": "string"},
  ]
}
```

> build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.21.RELEASE'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
group = 'com.example.kafka'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('spring-kafka.version', "2.2.8.RELEASE")
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

it's working setup and I am able to send and receive data, what changes I need to make in order to get Avro working.

Answer (score 3):

Confluent maintains tutorials for exactly this use case: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java-springboot.html

---

You're currently using only JSON, not "JSON schema". To use Avro easily with your current setup, you'd have to import the Jackson **Avro** data format `Objectmapper`.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/blob/master/avro/README.md

**Alternatively** (recommended) you can install/run the Confluent Schema Registry and use their serializers without having to write your own for every object class you want. Confluent provides `KafkaAvroSerializer` class for this purpose so you don't need to implement your own.

To actually use the AVSC, you will need to read the file from the filesystem to create a Schema object, or can use the Avro Gradle Plugin to have it generate a object class for you rather than you writing one manually, which will have the schema embedded as a variable. https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-avro-plugin

The Confluent examples use the Avro Maven plugin, but the idea would be similar.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html#example-producer-code

Note that using the Jackson Avro encoded messages are not compatible with Confluent ones, as the Confluent serialized messages do not contain any Avro schema themselves, so you cannot mix those (de)serializers

Comment: it might sound stupid, but I didn't understand most of your answer. could you please explain it with an example.

Comment: It's hard to explain because you're doing a lot, actually... I would start with the simple example provided here - https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html#client-applications-writing-avro (Which does not use Spring or Gradle, then try to find the proper replacements for what you actually want to do with those other tools).

Comment: "Note that using the Jackson Avro encoded messages are not compatible with Confluent ones, as the Confluent serialized messages do not contain any Avro schema themselves, so you cannot mix those (de)serializers" - what? One of those must have a bug then, right? Or is it the avro format itself that's defective (obviously it is, but with regardless to this specific issue.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare No. Confluent encodes an integer ahead of the actual Avro data to refer to the schema ID in the Registry. It doesn't include a schema in the data, only that ID. Jackson has nothing to do with Schema Registry implementations, therefore has no ID, and therefore is not able to deserialize data serialized with Confluent's serializer. In other words, serialization implementations must match